# mongodb 1.8.0 crashing on Windows 2008 R2

Tags: mongodb, crash, windows-server-2008-r2

Occasionally the mongod.exe process will crash for no apparent 
reason... it just started happening about 2 weeks ago. It's currently 
running in the console but it has done this when running as a service 
as well. 
Currently running with these parameters:

`mongod --directoryperdb --rest --autoresync --journal`

Here is the error from the event log:

```
Fault bucket 40795872, type 4 
Event Name: APPCRASH 
Response: Not available 
Cab Id: 0 
Problem signature: 
P1: mongod.exe 
P2: 0.0.0.0 
P3: 4d80db9b 
P4: mongod.exe 
P5: 0.0.0.0 
P6: 4d80db9b 
P7: c0000005 
P8: 00000000000d6d13 
P9: 
P10: 
Attached files: 
C:\Users\Radmin\AppData\Local\Temp 
\3\WERC9EC.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml 
C:\Users\Radmin\AppData\Local\Temp\3\WERDF50.tmp.appcompat.txt 
C:\Users\Radmin\AppData\Local\Temp\3\WERF274.tmp.mdmp 
These files may be available here: 
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive 
\AppCrash_mongod.exe_61ea717241ade5aa4decd5529bdc4de44acb2f_8f452c76 
Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0 
Report Id: 6acec6a3-bc8d-11e0-804b-0026b94f280e 
Report Status: 9
```

And here is the contents of the Windows Error Report listed above:

```
Version=1 
EventType=APPCRASH 
EventTime=129567112402581947 
ReportType=2 
Consent=1 
UploadTime=129567112404922157 
ReportIdentifier=6acec6a4-bc8d-11e0-804b-0026b94f280e 
IntegratorReportIdentifier=6acec6a3-bc8d-11e0-804b-0026b94f280e 
Response.BucketId=40795872 
Response.BucketTable=4 
Response.type=4 
Sig[0].Name=Application Name 
Sig[0].Value=mongod.exe 
Sig[1].Name=Application Version 
Sig[1].Value=0.0.0.0 
Sig[2].Name=Application Timestamp 
Sig[2].Value=4d80db9b 
Sig[3].Name=Fault Module Name 
Sig[3].Value=mongod.exe 
Sig[4].Name=Fault Module Version 
Sig[4].Value=0.0.0.0 
Sig[5].Name=Fault Module Timestamp 
Sig[5].Value=4d80db9b 
Sig[6].Name=Exception Code 
Sig[6].Value=c0000005 
Sig[7].Name=Exception Offset 
Sig[7].Value=00000000000d6d13 
DynamicSig[1].Name=OS Version 
DynamicSig[1].Value=6.1.7600.2.0.0.274.10 
DynamicSig[2].Name=Locale ID 
DynamicSig[2].Value=1033 
DynamicSig[22].Name=Additional Information 1 
DynamicSig[22].Value=83a2 
DynamicSig[23].Name=Additional Information 2 
DynamicSig[23].Value=83a22b68adabd8160bbb925ad2027dfd 
DynamicSig[24].Name=Additional Information 3 
DynamicSig[24].Value=1c66 
DynamicSig[25].Name=Additional Information 4 
DynamicSig[25].Value=1c66d59401ac277933dc0038bdb09634 
UI[2]=d:\mongodb\mongod.exe 
UI[3]=mongod.exe has stopped working 
UI[4]=Windows can check online for a solution to the problem. 
UI[5]=Check online for a solution and close the program 
UI[6]=Check online for a solution later and close the program 
UI[7]=Close the program 
LoadedModule[0]=d:\mongodb\mongod.exe 
LoadedModule[1]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll 
LoadedModule[2]=C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll 
LoadedModule[3]=C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll 
LoadedModule[4]=C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll 
LoadedModule[5]=C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll 
LoadedModule[6]=C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll 
LoadedModule[7]=C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll 
LoadedModule[8]=C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll 
LoadedModule[9]=C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll 
LoadedModule[10]=C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL 
LoadedModule[11]=C:\Windows\system32\cryptbase.dll 
LoadedModule[12]=C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll 
LoadedModule[13]=C:\Windows\system32\user32.dll 
LoadedModule[14]=C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll 
LoadedModule[15]=C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll 
LoadedModule[16]=C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll 
LoadedModule[17]=C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL 
LoadedModule[18]=C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll 
LoadedModule[19]=C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll 
LoadedModule[20]=C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll 
LoadedModule[21]=C:\Windows\system32\IPHLPAPI.DLL 
LoadedModule[22]=C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL 
LoadedModule[23]=C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll 
LoadedModule[24]=C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll 
LoadedModule[25]=C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll 
LoadedModule[26]=C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll 
LoadedModule[27]=C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll 
LoadedModule[28]=C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll 
LoadedModule[29]=C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll 
State[0].Key=Transport.DoneStage1 
State[0].Value=1 
State[1].Key=DataRequest 
State[1].Value=iData=1/nDumpFile=//Upload//iCab// 
9D328422129D43B6A9A86E07F40E5C25.cab/ 
nDumpServer=WATSON109.watson.microsoft.com/ 
nResponseServer=WATSON109.watson.microsoft.com/nResponseURL=//dw// 
StageFour64.asp? 
iBucket=40795872&szCab=9D328422129D43B6A9A86E07F40E5C25.cab&EventType=AppCr ash64&MID=11F36DEB-03A4-4E29- 
B2CF-27068A19AE20/nBucket=40795872/nBucketTable=4/nResponse=1/n 
FriendlyEventName=Stopped working 
ConsentKey=APPCRASH 
AppName=mongod.exe 
AppPath=d:\mongodb\mongod.exe
```

Comment: You'll want to report this on the mongodb issue tracker at jira.mongodb.com.

Comment: Also make sure you are running the 64-bit version and not the 32-bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Update to Mongodb 2.0.0 is now Production Release](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads)